# How can I make Maven/Surefire run the tests only in the modules specified by the -pl argument

Tags: maven, testing, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a multi-module Maven projects. And I often run maven for a single module (`pl`) plus its dependencies (`-am`):

```
mvn test -pl module -am
```

This will start running the tests on all the dependencies as well. Is there a way to tell Surefire to only run the tests in the module/s (the one/s specified by the `-pl` argument, `module` in the example above) and skip all the tests in all the modules collected by using the `-am` option.

Notes:

- I cannot use test whitelisting using the `-Dtest=...` because the package do guarantee that no tests from another module will be executed.
- If I don't use the `-am` option, the build will fail because of the dependencies from the same project that will not be found (and since I am in a Dockerized environments, I don't have the luxury of the cached artifacts in the `.m2/repository`)

Comment: Simple answer: No cause by using `-am` means to build all modules which are needed by the `module`. The only option to prevent this a fore up `mvn clean instal` and than you can use `mvn test -pl module` without `-am`...otherwise the modules run also the unit tests...the question is why do you not use the IDE to run tests from `module`?

Answer (score 1):

I have applied the following `sed` workaround in my scripts to solve this problem. Basically, I add the `<skipTests>true</skipTests>` configuration for the `maven-surefire-plugin` in all modules of my project with the exception (hence the `git checkout` command) of my current module (denoted below by variable `MAVEN_MODULE`):

```
echo "==> Forcibly disabling of tests in all dependency modules"
for pom in */pom.xml
do
  sed -i '/<plugins>/a <plugin><groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId><artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId><configuration><skipTests>true</skipTests></configuration></plugin>' $pom
done
git checkout "${MAVEN_MODULE}"
```

where the `sed` command adds the following XML fragment in the `<plugins>` section of each child module `pom.xml` file:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue with profiles and properties.

## parent `pom.xml`,

### properties

`skip.test` - to skip surefire and/or failsafe plugin.
`skip.x.test` - `x` is one of modules, define this for each sub-modules.
For example,

```
<properties>
    <skip.tests>false</skip.tests>
    <skip.x.tests>false</skip.x.tests>
    <skip.y.tests>false</skip.y.tests>
    <skip.z.tests>false</skip.z.tests>
</properties>
```

### plugin configs

Put this element into surefire and/or failsafe plugin execution.

```
<skipTests>${skip.tests}</skipTests>
```

For example,

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>${skip.tests}</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

### profiles

Define a profile to enable tests for only the specified module. You need this for each module.
For example,

## module `pom.xml`

### properties

In module `x`, define this to override the `skip.tests` property.

```
<properties>
    <skip.tests>${skip.x.tests}</skip.tests>
</properties>
```

## command

```
maven test -pl x -am -Dtest.x
```